# Set PATH for Apache on per-directory basis?

Tags: apache

How to set PATH for Apache server on a per-directory basis?

Problem: I have a system in which I can not change the 
system installed python in /usr/bin/.

I have a bunch of python cgi scripts that all have
 `#!/usr/bin/env python` 
as their first line.  I strongly prefer not to change
these scripts for logistical reasons.

But these scripts require a different version of Python
than the system installed one.  I have the right version
installed in /opt/python/bin/.  So if I could put this 
directory at the front of PATH, but only for this particular
cgi directory, it would solve my problem.

That is, if the following would work, it would do what I want.

```
    ScriptAlias /mydir/cgi/ /home/me/devel/cgi/
      <Directory /home/me/devel/cgi>
        SetEnv PATH /opt/python/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
        ...other stuff...
      </Directory>
```

But it seems SetEnv does not work on PATH (at least on Apache 2.2).

Is there some other way to changing PATH for just one 
particular directory in Apache?

(P.S., I also tried SetEnvIf without any joy.)